# Define a variable to satisfy $x^3 = -x$, then sum to find exponential

Tags: equation-solving, ncalgebra

I'm wondering if it is possible to tell Mathematica that my non-commuting variable satisfies $x^3 = -x$ such that it can compute $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(Ax)^n}{n!} = e^{Ax} = \cos A+ x \sin A$ with the `Sum` function, where $A \in \mathbb{R}$

I've tried it with the NCAlgebra package but now if I compute

```
Sum[(x A)^n/n!, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

nothing happens. Here `A` is commuting and `x` non-commuting.

I'm not hung up on the NCAlgebra package, any way to simplify the sum to elementary functions is appreciated. But fundamental to the solution has to be that I can tell Mathematica that $x^3 = -x$, because my real target is to see if Mathematica can rewrite a sum where I know that $x^3 = -x + y$ with known $x$ and $y$.

p.s. possible solutions of such variables would be a normalized [Pauli vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Pauli_vector) $\vec{\sigma}$ or a [vectorial quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Scalar_and_vector_parts).

Comment: (1) If `A` commutes with everything the given that `x` commutes with itself this can be treated as the ordinary commuting case. (2) Imposing that rule can be done by splitting off the constant term and then splitting the rest into even and odd terms, corresponding to `x` and `x^2`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, that is true, but the problem is that e.g. $\sin(\theta x)$ does not exist, I'd like to get something like $x \sin(\theta)$ just like you would with e.g. SU(2) matrices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector. This is why I thought perhaps with NCAlgebra such rules would be respected.

Comment: Okay, I am still not fully following, but I may be closer. What I think you want is something like `MatrixFunction` but with a replacement rule that might force you to code your own variant.But I still think the splitting idea will help...

Comment: ...Something like this. If `f` has a Taylor series with nth term `f[n]`, then `f[Ax] = f[0] + Sum[(-1)^((j-1)/2) f[j],{j,1,Infinity,2}].x + Sum[(-1)^(j/2) f[j],{j,2,Infinity,2}].x^2`